# Run JS function on page load if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following link which opens a dom window...

```
<a href='#inlineContent' class='defaultDOMWindow'>(edit interests)</a><br /><br />";?>

    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    $('.defaultDOMWindow').openDOMWindow({ 
    eventType:'click', 
    loader:1, 
    loaderImagePath:'animationProcessing.gif', 
    loaderHeight:16, 
    loaderWidth:17 
    }); 
    </script> 
    <div id='inlineContent' style='display: none;'> 
    <h1 class='login-hdr'>Your Interests!</h1>
```

What I need to do is if a user visits a certain url eg, www.mysite.com#DOMwindow the DOM window would then load without the user having to click the link, but if he visits the url normally with www.mysite.com the window would not load, im not sure if this is possible but thought id ask...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `openDOMWindow()` does, but I suspect/guess it is attaching a click event to `.defaultDOMWindow`. If so, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.defaultDOMWindow').openDOMWindow({ 
        eventType:'click', 
        loader:1, 
        loaderImagePath:'animationProcessing.gif', 
        loaderHeight:16, 
        loaderWidth:17 
    });
    // if the visitor requests www.mysite.com#DOMwindow
    // trigger a click event on the .defaultDOMWindow
    // thus the window will be opened automatically on load time
    if(window.location.hash == '#DOMwindow'){
        $('.defaultDOMWindow').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Liam - `location.hash` will include `#`, so this just needs a slight tweak: `window.location.hash == '#DOMwindow'`.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks, forgot it, was going to add it just now. :)